# Falha na transação. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.7.1 <email>: Relay access denied

Tags: asp.net, email, asp, smtp

Tenho este código para envio de e-mails e está retornando o seguinte erro:

> Falha na transação. A resposta do servidor foi: 5.7.1 : Relay access denied

Alguém saberia me dizer o problema? Já verifiquei senha, porta, host e está tudo ok.

```
        string nomeRemetente = "Contato";
        string emailRemetente = "email";
        string assuntoMensagem = assunto;
        MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
        objEmail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(nomeRemetente + "<" + emailRemetente + ">");
        foreach (var dest in destinatarios)
        {
            objEmail.To.Add(new MailAddress(dest));
        }
        objEmail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("emailbcc"));
        objEmail.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal;
        objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        objEmail.Subject = assuntoMensagem;
        objEmail.Body = conteudoMensagem;
        objEmail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        objEmail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8");
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient objSmtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        objSmtp.Host = "smtp.com.br";
        //objSmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        objSmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        objSmtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(emailRemetente, "senha");
        objSmtp.Port = 587;

        try
        {
            objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            objEmail.Dispose();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este erro geralmente está relacionado a autenticação, se os dados estão corretos pode ser que o servidor exija o uso de SSL, que pode ser ativado setando a propriedade `EnableSsl` como `true` do `SmtpClient`

Comment: Quando eu coloco o `EnableSsl` ele aparece a mensagem o servidor não oferece suporte para conexões seguras.